# open ms-settings:notifications settings for specified app C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to open this window through my program?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdEWc.png)
I'm trying with

```
static string uriToLaunch = "ms-settings:notifications";
Uri uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

but don't know correct syntax after "notifications" (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that.

However as a workaround, you can include a small guide like this:

[image: sample guide made in mspaint]

Comment: Sorry for the potato quality paint picture.